# how to maintain indentation when showing file with html5 file api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fileapi

I am trying to some simple text files with HTML5 file api like css,js,etc. but I lost indentation when displaying .

how could I get indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code in the <pre>...</pre> element

Comment: thanks that could me great idea but is there any formatting libraries?

Comment: The one that is probably used most is http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/download/ but download the version 2.0.x version.

Comment: The link for the syntax highlighter handles most languages HTML, CSS, JavaScript, PHP and more : http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/